# Python - how to for loop an array from not 0th but xth element?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, image-processing, deep-learning

I have a `for` loop like this

```
ImgPaths = make_dataset(TestImgPath)
    for i, ImgPath in enumerate(ImgPaths):
```

In which:

- TestImgPath is the path to input images. Type string. In my case `TestImgPath = './TestData/TestWhole'`. `TestData` and `TestWhole` are folders.
- ImgPath is the path to image. For example `ImgPath = ./TestData/TestWhole\XXXXX.jpg` when I print. XXXXX is 00000 to 82700 in my case
- ImgPath is the path to images at once. For example `ImgPaths = ./TestData/TestWhole\\XXXXX.jpg` when I print. But I think it is the entire 00000-XXXXX in one, since `ImgPaths` is assigned like above.

So, there are 82700 files to handle, and it takes 24 seconds for one file. Wait for it to be done entirely at once is too long. The parent folder is large so I cannot duplicate the parent folder into 10 copies and execute every single copy. So dividing that `for` loop may be the way to go. Seems like it is not a normal `for` loop but an array `for` loop.

So, how to make an array `for` loop start and stop at a certain element? If I want to start from 11111.jpg and stop at 22222.jpg, how to do it?

This is the source code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jnE7kSK2eyXEAsTXb_4IctUEbBkZSWJa/view?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional statement to skip processing until `i` reaches the desired starting number, and then `break` the loop when `i` exceeds the ending number:

```
for i, ImgPath in enumerate(ImgPaths):
    if i > 22222:
        break
    elif i >= 11111:
        # process ImgPath
```

or use `itertools.islice` to limit the iterations to the specified range:

```
import itertools
for ImgPath in itertools.islice(ImgPaths, 11111, 22222 + 1):
    # process ImgPath
```